# Google cloud storage: change bucket region

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I'm using google cloud storage.
I have created a bucket in US, and now I need to move it to EU, due to GDPR.
Is there any way to change the bucket location?

If not, In case of removing the bucket and creating a new one instead - can I give it the same name? (as it is globally unique).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, as per Cloud Storage [**documentation**](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/moving-buckets), you can move or rename your bucket:

> - If there is no data in your old bucket, delete the bucket and create another bucket with a new name, in a new location, or in a new
>     project.
> - If you have data in your old bucket, create a new bucket with the desired name, location, and/or project, copy data from the old bucket
>     to the new bucket, and delete the old bucket and its contents. *(The link provided above describes this process)*.

Keep in mind that if you would like your new bucket to have the **same name** as your old bucket, you must move your data **twice**: an intermediary bucket temporarily holds your data so that you can delete the original bucket and free up the bucket name for the final bucket.